# SSIS unable to access the component's advanced editor

Tags: json, ssis, kingswaysoft

I am using the Kingswaysoft connection manager to manage Oauth2 for the DocuSign rest API.  My JSON source component is throwing the below error:

"The output value for 'name' systemField does not fit into the output buffer, please consider increasing the output column's Length property or changing its data type to one that can accommodate more data such as ntext (DT_NTEXT). This change can be done using the component's Advanced Editor window.".

When I try to edit the columns length property I am unable to see anyway to change it using the advanced editor.  The only thing I see under the advanced section is a checkbox for "Enabled Http request output"

Looking at the columns section of the JSON source component I can see that the "Name" field is nvarchar 50, but I am unable to edit the length.

Looking under document designer, I can select the node that contains the Name field and change the value, but I can only make that edit for each record AND setting it for the first record doesn't change the result.

Also I am unable to use the preview feature of the JSON component as my Rest API command is parameterized with input from a For Each Loop object.

Any suggestions for how to work around the error?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Have you tried editing the datatype in the underlying package xml?

Comment: Found the solution.  The Advance Editor is NOT the Advance menu option you see when editing the package.  Rather the "Advanced Editor" is accessed via a right click on the JSON source object.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. The Advance Editor is NOT the Advance menu option you see when editing the package. Rather the "Advanced Editor" is accessed via a right click on the JSON source object.

Comment: Glad you found the solution, Thanks for sharing.